# What is the most secure way to Create a Process with Admin Rights?

Tags: c#, windows, security

I have a server that  uses the CreateProcess function to launch a client program which requires administrative rights. I am hesitant to do this because all a hacker would have to is replace their program `hacker.exe` in the same location as my client program and give it the name `totallysafeclient.exe` which my server will launch with administrative rights.

I was thinking of using [System.Security.Cryptography](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307020#bookmark-3) to calculate the hash of `totallysafeclient.exe` to determine if it is indeed what it says it is. Thoughts?

Comment: What if it loads a DLL? Especially if it can load DLLs from the current directory?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2014/05/13/load-library-safely/

Comment: Why don't you put `totallysafeclient.exe` in a part of the file system (such as Program Files) where only an administrator could modify it?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I didn't know that Program Files has that kind of protection, do you happen to have a reference for that?

Comment: Just look at the file system permissions.

Comment: There is no secure way.  It is the job of UAC to make it secure.  The program you start must have a manifest that contains "requireAdministrator" or use the runas verb.  The user must approve and provide the admin credentials.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Isn't that putting a lot of trust in the UAC and the user? For example, nearly everyone uses Adobe Flash, all a hacker would have to do is replace AdobeARM.exe and the user would just assume once the UAC prompt appears that it's from Adobe

Comment: AdobeARM.exe lives in Program Files, so if the hacker can change it, they [already have administrator access](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060508-22/?p=31283).  But I'm not sure what that has to do with your scenario anyway.  What's your threat model here?  (If you are downloading the file you certainly should check the digital signature before running it.  But that doesn't seem to be what you were asking about.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research, using [System.Security.Cryptography](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307020#bookmark-3) is a very poor choice because Windows already has a builtin mechanism involving RSA encryption called [Code Signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx). Signing your code allows users to know where code comes from and if it has been **tampered with**.

[ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) is a much better choice than CreateProcessAsUser because it can handle `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED` exceptions by using UAC. Most users *and developers* hated (and probably still do) when Vista came out with this but I highly encourage you to watch [UAC - What. How. Why.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/UAC-What-How-Why) where both the Project Lead and System Architect of UAC explain why it was needed and how it has increased security.